# Python 3.4.3 & Bottle with CGI - environ['REQUEST_METHOD']

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to use Python 3.4.3 and Bottle 0.12.8 to run a simple web service using cgi. I am running the below script from my Linux system. I was able to run the the same service without CGI.

```
======================================
import bottle
from bottle import route, run, request, response

host = 'XXXX'
port = '8080'
debug = 'False'

@route('/hello/',  method=['OPTIONS','GET'])
def hello():
    return("Success")

bottle.run(host=host, port=port,debug=debug,server='cgi')
#bottle.run(host=host, port=port,debug=debug)
======================================
```

I get the below error, when I run the service with CGI-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 858, in _handle
    route, args = self.router.match(environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 413, in match
    verb = environ['REQUEST_METHOD'].upper()
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
<h1>Critical error while processing request: </h1><h2>Error:</h2>
<pre>
KeyError(&#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,)
</pre>
<h2>Traceback:</h2>
<pre>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py&quot;, line 957, in wsgi
    or environ[&#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;] == &#039;HEAD&#039;:
KeyError: &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;

</pre>
Status: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 374

<h1>Critical error while processing request: </h1><h2>Error:</h2>
<pre>
KeyError(&#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;,)
</pre>
<h2>Traceback:</h2>
<pre>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py&quot;, line 957, in wsgi
    or environ[&#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;] == &#039;HEAD&#039;:
KeyError: &#039;REQUEST_METHOD&#039;

</pre>

Any pointers would help. Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the [basic CGI HTTP server in Python](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/http/server.py) only supports GET, HEAD and POST commands. CGI server is throwing the KeyError when it attempts to validate the OPTIONS command. If you want to use the OPTIONS method in your server code, you'll need implement it yourself or switch to a different server.

Comment: Thanks Cahit. I used CherryPy for now in my implementation.